# How to pass JSON from wicket to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wicket

I have the following function in java script page that call wicket ajax:

```
function callWicketPage() {  
                wicketAjaxGet(
                urlCallback,
                function() {alert('success'); },
                function() { alert('failed');
                }); 
            }
```

and in the wicket page I do the following:

```
   final AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior behave = new AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior() { 
    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse ihr) {
        super.renderHead(ihr);
        ihr.renderJavascript("var urlCallback = '" + this.getCallbackUrl() + "';", "insertedjavascript");
    } 
        protected void respond(final AjaxRequestTarget target) { 
        }
    };
    add(behave);
```

What i want is to send back a json response from the wicket page to JavaScript, How could i do it \?

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you to use a `ResourceReference` instead, so you don't have to get read/write access to page instance (and mount it for easier access from your client side script).

But if you want to keep your behavior based solution:

```
class JsonBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);

        // please define the channel type (default: queue)
        attributes.setChannel(new AjaxChannel("json"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        RequestCycle rc = RequestCycle.get();

        rc.replaceAllRequestHandlers(new TextRequestHandler("application/json", "UTF-8", "{'json':'content'}"));
    }
}
```